# Why Does the Infopath 2007 Form Shows Error Message When Saving Repeating Table With More Than 60 Records?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, infopath

We are currently creating an InfoPath 2007 form is deployed in SharePoint 2007. In the form we populate the repeating tables with more than 60 records. However, when we're submitting the form, an error message appears. Does the number of records in the repeating table affects the submitting of the form? Also provide some workaround to resolve the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the number of postbacks allowed when filling out the form is set by default to be around 75 or so. I had a  similar issue and had to raise the limit in the Central Admin page.

Answer (score 0):

I have had repeating tables with many more than 60 records, so that is probably not your problem.  What is the error your are getting.